# How to fix misaligned rows alt the last records, after using vertical scroll and frozen column?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid, without pagination and ordination, but I have the first column frozen. I have known number of records, 30 records. I set the height bigger than the total of the number of records, there are no problems.

But, if I set the height less than the number or records, so vertical scroll is able to be used. Scrolling the first rows, there are no problems too, but when I got the final records, I can see a little misaligned on the last rows, between the first cell (frozen column) and the other cells.

I'm trying to change some elements on CSS file, but without success.

How could I fix this problem?

See the images:

[image]

After scrolling (see the last rows):

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? I develop free jqGrid fork and have fixed many problem with frozen columns existing in old version. First of all I'd recommend you to modify the references to 3 jqGrid files to CDN URLs of free jqGrid 4.13.3. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) for details. I hope that the problem is not exist in free jqGrid 4.13.3.

Comment: My idea was to use the free version, but now, reading your comment, I start believing that I didn't get the free version. I just googled "download jqGrid" and went to [Trirand page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6). The version was "Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.1.0.zip".  I will try to get the version from your link.

Comment: You can get the source code of Guriddo, but one can't use it for free. You can find the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Changing license agreement in 4.7.1 was the reason why I made the fork of 4.7 (the latest version available under MIT license). I develop it now under the name [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). You can use it from CDN, npm package, NuGet package, etc. See [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) for more details. I implemented many new features and fixed old bugs. See readmes to every published version.

Comment: Oleg, sorry for my long delay, but you were right!! I just donwload the free jqGrid, and this problem didn't happen anymore, at least on Chrome. on IE, It's continue, but that's ok, because before using the jqGrid, the another solution has problem with IE. IE is sucks.. :D  Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to try to switch from Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.1.0 to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.3, which I develop. Starting with version 4.10.0 (of free jqGrid) I rewrote many parts of implementation of frozen columns and I hope that you will don't have the described problem.